# File write in C confusion

Tags: c, file

Hi I am appending  at the bottom of the text file this works on windows but on linux instead of appending to the bottom it appends to the top of the text file. The code i am using is. The code must only use C

```
FILE *fout;
fout = fopen("dat.txt","a");  
fprintf(fout,"&& ");
fclose(fout);
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: That looks good to me. I don't have a Linux with me, but it's certainly fine on the Solaris that I have here.

Comment: Works fine on linux too. If you do anything else with that file handle in your actual code (anywhere), post that too.

Comment: Once or twice, I've had particularly sticky situations where ccache seemed to be causing me problems in the compile/test cycle.  If, in your Linux home directory, there is a hidden directory called ".ccache" - try removing it.  Just a whim, but that code is right, so the problem isn't in what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Check for errors returned from those system calls - that code looks correct.  Also, check to make sure you aren't accidentally mangling dat.txt elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled on Mac OS (Linux) and it works as advertised, e.g. the line was appended at the end.

Are you doing something else with the file?

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok. check your code again, maybe you are repostioning the file pointer, with frewind or fseek somewhere. A better way is to use the "a+" option. You should also check the return value fout from fopen.

Comment: fseek and friends should not affect the write position of a file opened in append mode. Writes to append mode files always go to the end of file. If they don't, then the underlying C library is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

If you do anything else with that file before the append, make sure you are closing it.